# wkhtmltoimage-amd64 with php

Tags: php

I am trying to use wkhtmltoimage on linux hosting that allows shell_exec and exec commands. system is Centos 64bit. i have download wkhtmltoimage-amd64 extension and upload to the server. when i execute commands nothing happened

I am failed to use this.

here it is my code
echo shell_exec("wkhtmltoimage-amd64 http://google.com/ test.png");

also I try with shell access but no use,

please can you guide me how can i use this and make it working on my hosting

Shall be thankful

Answer (score 0):

Look into the webservers `error.log`. It will probably tell you that the command wasn't found. The current directory is seldomly in the search path. Prefix the binary name with `./` if it resides in the same directory as your php script.

```
shell_exec("./wkhtmltoimage-amd64 http://google.com/ test.png");
```

You can also add `2>&1` after the command to have stderr output returned from shell_exec (in case of other issues).